# Generating an array of integers in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Is there a simple way in **TypeScript** to **generate an array of the first 10 integer numbers**?

Such as I would do with **Matlab** with `x = 1:10`.

Comment: There is no built in syntax but you can easily build a helper function that takes `from` and `to` and returns array between them.

Comment: `Array(10).fill(0).map((i, idx) => idx + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Parameters) where you can use index inside map function o generate the number.

```js
console.log(
  Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array.prototype.fill` and `Array.prototype.map`

```js
let arr = Array(10).fill(0);
arr = arr.map((val, index) => index + 1);
console.log(arr);
```